# LINUX IPC: Passing different values to CHILD process using PIPE not working, except for first time, in C

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I have a set of taskids grouped in to several groups, each identified by a unique  `groupid`.

1. For each `group`, I need to spawn a child process (*each of them act as servers - means they get messages from other processes and return the results after processing*).
2. Each child is entitled to serve exclusively for the `GROUP` it is associated with. Hence I want to pass a unique `groupId` to each child process right after spawning, so that it will do only the tasks associated with its `groupId`.
3. There's only writing of `groupId` by the PARENT to CHILD, that too only one time, at the time of CHILD spawn. CHILD is not supposed to write back anything to PARENT. (one way communication - `PARENT - write/CHILD -read`)

After a bit research, I wrote a pseudo code as below. (this is a compilable code).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int process(int n);

#define NGROUPID 5
#define INIT_GROUPID 1000

int parent_to_child[2];
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid_t pid_array[NGROUPID];  //Child pid array.
    int groupId[NGROUPID];
    int groupID = 0,i;

    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));  //random seed
    groupId[0] = INIT_GROUPID;

    printf("[0.1] ");
    //set groupIds 
    for(i=1; i < (NGROUPID - 1); i++)
    {
        int j = i -1;
        groupId[i]= groupId[j] + 2;
        printf("%d~%d\t",j,groupId[j]);

    }
    printf("%d~%d\n",i-1,groupId[i-1]);

    fflush(stdout); //Flushing stdout before pipe call
    pipe(parent_to_child);

    // For each groupId, spawn child process 
    for (i = 0; i < (NGROUPID - 1); i++ )
    {

        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            process(i); //Child Process.
            break;  //Is it necessory to break? Will it create Children of children?
        }
        if(pid > 0)
        {
            close(parent_to_child[0]); //parent is not reading from child
            printf("[1.1] writing to child: %d parent %d i %d groupId %d\n",pid,getpid(),i,groupId[i]);
            write(parent_to_child[1], &groupId[i], sizeof(int)); //Passing groupId to Child.
            pid_array[i] = pid;  //To shutdown cleanly.
        }
    }
    if(pid > 0)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < (NGROUPID - 1); i++ )
        {
            printf("[1.2] waiting for pid: %d\n",pid_array[i]);
            waitpid(pid_array[i], NULL, 0);
            printf("[1.3] Finished pid: %d\n",pid_array[i]);
        }

    }

    printf("[0.2] Did we Finished total %d PID %d\n", NGROUPID, getpid());
    if(pid > 0)
        printf("[1.4] There are no zombies\n");

    return 0;

}

//This is a pseudo code. Actual code will consists of receiving messages
// from other processes (using message queue) and return the results after processing.
// This act like a SERVER process, which will not quit in usual scenario. 
int process(int n)
{
    int groupID = 0;
    close(parent_to_child[1]); //we are not going to return to Parent.
    read(parent_to_child[0], &groupID, sizeof(int)); //Read from Parent
    unsigned int sec = (rand() % 10) + 1;
    printf("[2.1] Processing %d th Process pid: %d groupId %d sleep %d sec\n",n, getpid(), groupID, sec);
    sleep(sec);
    printf("[2.2] Returning from sleep %d Process pid: %d groupId %d sleep %d sec\n",n, getpid(), groupID, sec);
}
```

The output of this program is below:

```
    [0.1] 0~1000    1~1002  2~1004  3~1006
    [1.1] writing to child: 15068 parent 15067 i 0 groupId 1000
    [2.1] Processing 0 th Process pid: 15068 groupId 1000 sleep 3 sec
    [1.1] writing to child: 15069 parent 15067 i 1 groupId 1002
    [2.1] Processing 1 th Process pid: 15069 groupId 0 sleep 3 sec
    [1.1] writing to child: 15070 parent 15067 i 2 groupId 1004
    [2.1] Processing 2 th Process pid: 15070 groupId 0 sleep 3 sec
    [1.1] writing to child: 15071 parent 15067 i 3 groupId 1006
    [1.2] waiting for pid: 15068
    [2.1] Processing 3 th Process pid: 15071 groupId 0 sleep 3 sec

    // This Gap is not a part of output. It indicates the sleep worked from here.

    [2.2] Returning from sleep 0 Process pid: 15068 groupId 1000 sleep 3 sec
    [0.2] Did we Finished total 5 PID 15068
    [2.2] Returning from sleep 1 Process pid: 15069 groupId 0 sleep 3 sec
    [0.2] Did we Finished total 5 PID 15069
    [1.3] Finished pid: 15068
    [1.2] waiting for pid: 15069
    [1.3] Finished pid: 15069
    [1.2] waiting for pid: 15070
    [2.2] Returning from sleep 2 Process pid: 15070 groupId 0 sleep 3 sec
    [0.2] Did we Finished total 5 PID 15070
    [1.3] Finished pid: 15070
    [1.2] waiting for pid: 15071
    [2.2] Returning from sleep 3 Process pid: 15071 groupId 0 sleep 3 sec
    [0.2] Did we Finished total 5 PID 15071
```

The numbering system in the output is as below.

```
    [0.*] - Indicate that Print from General part of code (neither parent or child)
    [1.*] - Indicate that Print from PARENT process. (pid > 0)
    [2.*] - Indicate that Print from CHILD process.  (pid == 0)
```

There are few issues I am facing with this code.

**1. Random Number**
I relied on random numbers to produce uneven sleep time for CHILD, which mimic the actual scenario. Even though I have put `srand(time(NULL))` function up above in the `main` function, But `rand()` in the `process() function` always generate same output (`3 seconds` in above output). Is it because the CPU is so fast??. If yes, Is there any better seeds available?

**2. Reading PIPE**
Barring the first time, the `groupId`s read from CHILD process always become zero. As indicated by below output.

`[2.1] Processing 2 th Process pid: 15070 groupId 0 sleep 3 sec`

You can clearly see at the time of `write` by parent, `groupId` is picked up correctly. (as indicated below):

`[1.1] writing to child: 15070 parent 15067 i 2 groupId 1004`

How can I improve this code to achieve the results. OR is there  any flaw in this logic (I am asking this because I am a beginner in IPC without much prior experience). Should I need to implement a `critical section` for `groupId` array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html

Comment: Where are your error checks? `pipe`, `write`, `read`, `waitpid`, etc all can fail. (And `read`/`write` can read/write less data than requested.)

Comment: Perhaps you should check the return values of more library calls to see if they succeeded or not.  Note `rand()` is a Pseudo-Random Number Generator (PRNG): It's actually deterministic, not truly random, so when given the same seed and after calling it the same number of times, it always gives the same results.  And forked processes will definitely start from the same state.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @melpomene . That code was written in hurry. It is a psuedo code, not actual implementation. I will incorporate it. For the second part, should i put the read/write section in an infinite loop?

Comment: @aschepler Is this means that I should call `srand()` inside child process, I mean in that fork loop. I tried it, but with little success.

Comment: @UmeshCG You can't `srand` with the current time because all the processes are created at the same time. You could have the parent use its `rand()` to generate a new seed for each of them in the parent process.

Comment: @melpomene Does `getrandom()` supported by all glibc versions, I am in glibc version 2,17, but when I tried `man getrandom` in my linux box, it returned nothing.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html#VERSIONS

Comment: There are a few problems with the posted code, all in the `main()` function: 1) the variable (note the uppercase 'D') is not used. `int groupID = 0;`  2)  this line: `for(i=1; i < (NGROUPID - 1); i++)` only accesses index 1 and 2 of the array `groupId[]`

Comment: You could use something like `srand(time(NULL) + getpid())` in the child processes to get a different seed for each.

Comment: cont: 3) this line: `groupId[i]= groupId[j] + 2;` sets groupId[1] and groupId[2] to 1002 and 1003 (respectively) and does nothing with  groupId[3].   Suggest replacing the init code with: `int groupId[] = { 1000, 1002, 1004, 1006 };` and removing all the run time initialization of that array.

Comment: this line: `pipe(parent_to_child);` is only creating one pipe.  The parent is 'blindly' writing to that pipe.  It is anyones' guess as to which child process will get to/read that pipe.  Suggest generating a separate pipe for each child.  Note: this statement: `close(parent_to_child[0]);` will fail after the first iteration.

Comment: after the call to: `process()`  suggest (rather than a `break;` statement) calling: `exit();` then the later check after the loop: `if(pid > 0)` is not needed

Comment: these kinds of statements: `for (i = 0; i < (NGROUPID - 1); i++ ) are rather 'odd', especially since they never access the last entry in the array: groupId[].   Suggest using: `for (i = 0; i < NGROUPID; i++ )`

Comment: this final statement: `if(pid > 0)` is still looking at the 'pid' from the last call to `fork()`.   It does NOT prove that there are no 'zombies'  The calls to `waitpid()` do prove there are no zombies, IF each of those calls was successful.   For the code to know if the call is successful (or not) the code must check the returned value from the function.

Comment: to use IPC with several processes, use a 'unique' message ID when sending the packet and have the read(ers) of the packet only respond to those packets that have 'their' message ID.

Answer (score 1):

**Random number.** You call `srand` before you fork, so all children inherit the same seed, so their calls to `rand` will produce identical numbers. You can increment the seed inside the loop and have each child call `srand` on its own.

**Communication.** The parent closes `parent_to_child[0]` after spawning the first child, so later children inherit a closed pipe, and cannot receive `groupID` information through it. Only when all forking is finished should the parent close that pipe.